# What is the disadvantage of using a single superuser in linux?

Tags: linux, root

I just want to know about the risks one can face during using only one root user and no any other users for handling some of the simple tasks. How it can be harmful for security and data point of view of having only a superuser.

Answer (score 2):

So, you're about to blat your test project directory using, say `rm -rf *`.

Just before doing so, you pop into `/` to do a find and see if your files need to be deleted from other directories.

OR

You have two terminal screens open, one sitting in your project directory and one sitting in / which you are switching between and your last switch was to the root screen, or you accidentally hit <Alt>-`  (backquote) instead of <Alt>-<Tab> to go back to your project screen

OR

You were in a sub level in the project directory and while intending to `cd ..`, you instead did `cd /`

At this point you really, really don't want to do `rm -rf *`, but it's been a long day and you've been multitasking between different projects, and you haven't had enough coffee and while **every other time** you'd do a `pwd` before a `rm -rf`, this time you didn't.

Even power users can make a mistake.  Accidents do happen.  Not being 'root' while performing daily duties protects you, not only from malicious code coming in from the 'net or miscreants who have (legit or otherwise) access to your system, but also from yourself.

On top of that, if you access your system remotely, you absolutely want another user (not root).  The ability to access your system through `ssh` should never be allowed as the root user.

You don't want to find out the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you are the only user that uses the system, it's unnecessary to have more than one, maybe two users on a system. But one reason could be, that it's very dangerous for unexperienced users to have root-access, because you can literally destroy your system with some of the available commands.

So long story short: If there are other users who use the system, I would highly recommend to add more accounts, because that way you are able to check, which person has done which tasks(via logs etc) But if you are the only user and you think you've got enough experience to be root all the time, then I see no point in adding additional users.